# Abstract Class Call Generic Method with This - Won't Compile

Tags: c#, generics

I'm getting a compile-time error that my method call has some invalid arguments.

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public virtual List<ValidationResult> Validate<T>()
    {
        // This line causes the error:
        var validationResults = this.ValidateEntity<T>(this, true).ToList();
    }

    protected IEnumerable<ValidationResult> ValidateEntity<T>(T entity, bool ignoreNullViolations)
    {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

The class is abstract. That should be ok. I tried specifying the type of T in the method signature but that didn't help. Why won't this compile? I can't pass `this` to a method expecting a T parameter?

**EDIT** -- Possible solution:

```
public virtual List<ValidationResult> Validate<T>() where T : class
{
    var validationResults = this.ValidateEntity<T>(this as T, true).ToList();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Since T should only be a subclass, I think the class signature should change to be generic so that forces the subclass to set it. Then passing `this` wouldn't be such a hack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ValidateEntity` method is declared such that the first parameter is of type `T`.

Now look how you're calling it:

```
var validationResults = this.ValidateEntity<T>(this, true).ToList();
```

You're trying to implicitly convert `this` to `T` - what makes you think that *should* work?

Suppose I called:

```
foo.Validate<string>();
```

That would try to pass `this` to a method effectively expecting a `string` - that's clearly not going to work, as `this` is a reference to an instance of some concrete subclass of `EntityBase` - *not* a reference to a string.

Comment: Ah, so do I need my EntityBase class to be EntityBase<T>?

Comment: I added an edit to my post that shows a way to get it to compile. It feels like a hack. But your answer answers my question, so I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @BobHorn: Using `as` will only work when `this` *is* actually an instance of `T`. It's hard to know the best solution without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve.